# Adding integers to list, while making strings of numbers separated by space into integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to append both integers and strings, which I am trying to turn into integers, as they can only be numbers separated by space.
My current code:

```
def check(x):
    if type(x) == str:
        x = x.split()
        return x
    else:
        return x

Data = []
while True:
    try:
        numbers = input()
        if numbers !='':
            added = check(numbers)
            Data.append(added)
        else:
            print(Data)
            break
    except EOFError as error:
        print(Data)
        break
```

but that does not exactly do what I need.
For example inputs of

```
   1
   22
   1 2 3
```

Give me the output of

```
   [['1'], ['22'], ['2', '3', '4']]
```

While I desire the output of

```
[['1'], ['22'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your example input does not match your desired output. (Input says 1 2 3 but output says 2 3 4.) Would you edit your question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```py
Data.append(added)
```

with

```py
for d in added:
    Data.append([d])
```

then

```py
1
22
2 3 4

[['1'], ['22'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Above is good but this code also help you do your task

```
Data = []
while True:
  try:
    numbers = list(map(int,input().split()))
    if len(numbers)==0:
      print(Data)
      break
    else:
      Data.append(numbers)
  except:
    print(Data)
```

This also when we give input

```
2
22
1 2 3 4
```

When you don't give anything as input like a simple enter will break the infinite loop and then gives you the following output!. I think that function is really redundant!.
The output is

```
[[2],[22],[1,2,3,4]]
```

Hope this helps! Happy Learning:)